# Excel VBA Macro: Searching For Blank From Selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search through a selection from a table, find a value and then return a specific result.

The conditions I am trying are:

1. IF 'Name' = blank, return "N / A".
2. IF 'Result' = blank, OR "N/A", return "N / A".
3. IF 'Count' = 0, return "No", ELSE "Yes".

**The code I have tried so far is as follows:**

```
Sub DoStuffIfNotEmpty()

  Set M = Selection

  If Not IsEmpty(M) Then
     MsgBox "I'm not empty!"

  Else
     MsgBox "Empty Value"

  End If

End Sub
```

**Also for reference, here is the test table I have created:**

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wipLj.png)

Comment: keep in mind that something like `=""` will not be counted as "empty"... i recommend something like `LEN(M) = 0`... however... how do you want to search? there are multiple rows -> multiple outputs, what and how do you want your "answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Test()` sets up the worksheet and cells to examine -- if you want to work down a list of cells you can do it here -- and calls `DoStuffIfNotEmpty`, which examines the Name, Result and Count columns in order.  Its not even close to being elegant but there you go...

```
Sub Test()
    Dim cWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim CRange As Range

    Set cWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set CRange = cWorksheet.Range("A2:C2")
    MsgBox DoStuffIfNotEmpty(cWorksheet, CRange), vbOKOnly
End Sub

Function DoStuffIfNotEmpty(CurrWorksheet As Worksheet, CurrRange As Range) As String

    CurrWorksheet.Select
    CurrRange.Select

    Set m = Selection

    If m.Cells(1, 1) = "" Or IsNull(m.Cells(1, 1)) Then
        retmsg = "N/A"
    Else
        If m.Cells(1, 2) = "" Or IsNull(m.Cells(1, 2)) Or m.Cells(1, 2) = "N/A" Then
            retmsg = "N/A"
        Else
            If m.Cells(1, 3) = 0 Then
                retmsg = "No"
            Else
                retmsg = "Yes"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    DoStuffIfNotEmpty = retmsg

End Function
```